# Compiling static 32-bit Qt on 64 bit machine

Tags: compiler-errors, qt5, ubuntu-16.04

I have a 64 bit Ubuntu machine. And I have successfully managed to configure and compile Qt5 **static** libraries using the following configure options

```
-static
-release
-prefix /opt/Qt-5.8.1
-confirm-license
-nomake examples
-nomake tests
-opensource
-qt-xcb
-no-sql-psql
-skip qt3d
-fontconfig
```

Now, I want to create a **32-bit static Qt** build. So, I added an additional `-xplatform linux-g++-32` option while configuring.

But, I get the following two (unrelated?) errors

`ERROR: Feature 'fontconfig' was enabled, but the pre-condition '!config.win32 && !config.darwin && features.system-freetype && libs.fontconfig' failed.`

`ERROR: The OpenGL functionality tests failed!
You might need to modify the include and library search paths by editing QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL[_ES2],
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL[_ES2] and QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL[_ES2] in the mkspec for your platform.`

I think I am missing something small here - like missing 32-bit development libraries. But I don't know what I should be installing on my 64-bit machine to enable 32-bit cross-compilation.

If there be a quick and easy fix for the above errors, then please let me know.

Thanks 
Abhinav.

Comment: Cross-compiling Qt is kind of a nightmare. I would recommend doing it on an actual 32-bit system (I use VMware to run a 32-bit Linux distro.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so let me answer my own question. Or at least share what worked for me finally.

**Background**

Having successfully built Qt-5 on an Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit machine using the above options and thereafter successfully creating a **64-bit statically linked** executable for my project, I was now looking to do the same in 32 bits.

**Problem**

Could not close on the correct set of configuration options and build environment setup for 32-bits

**Solution**

1. `sudo apt-get install libfreetype6:i386`
2. `sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev:i386`

Then change the following options when calling `./configure` for Qt.

`-prefix (path-to-Qt32bit) -platform linux-g++-32 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`

Call `make` and then `make install`. 
Now, you will have a 32-bit build of Qt (on a 64-bit machine)

**Gotcha**

Despite doing the above, the generated 32-bit executable of my project wouldn't run on a 32-bit machine.

I thought it was a problem with my Qt build.

But turned out that I was running the executable on a Ubuntu-12.04 machine. And the `libfreetype` shipped in 12.04 does not have some methods like `FT_Property_Set`. Hence, I was seeing run-time `undefined symbol` errors.

As a result, even though the executable was compiled, it couldn't run. 
The solution for me was to just install Ubuntu 16.04 (32-bit). The executable then ran without a hitch.